# Dataframe populated by lists, how to reorder all the lists by reordering numerically all the lists in a specific column

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, sorting, dictionary

I have a dataframe generated by the below dictionary:

```
input_data= {'Names':[['Ed','Mark','Jim'],['Jiulia','Jhon'],['Phil']],
       'IDs' :[[5,2,3],[7,1],[10]],
       'Address':[['road x','road y','road v'],['road a','road b'],['road z']]}

| Names               | IDs           | Address                      |
| ------------------- | ------------- | ---------------------------- |
| ['Ed','Mark','Jim'] | ['5','2','3'] | ['road x','road y','road v'] |
| ['Jiulia','Jhon']   | ['7','1']     | ['road a','road b']          |
| ['Phil']            | ['10']        | ['road z']                   |
```

I need to find out how to reorder the ID elements inside the lists in the ID column of the dataframe and then reorder Names and Address accordingly to the IDs new order as shown by the table below which would be the output I need:

```
| Names               | IDs           | Address                      |
| ------------------- | ------------- | ---------------------------- |
| ['Mark','Jim','Ed'] | ['2','3','5'] | ['road y','road v','road x'] |
| ['Jhon','Jiulia']   | ['1','7']     | ['road b','road a']          |
| ['Phil']            | ['10']        | ['road z']                   |
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way do it
explode, sort and group it back

```
df.explode(['Names','IDs','Address']).sort_values('IDs').groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

As per your edited question, if quantities are string, this is one way about it, where you convert the IDs to int before sorting. result is same

```
df2=df.explode(['Names','IDs','Address'])
df2['IDs'] = df2['IDs'].astype('int')
df2.sort_values('IDs').groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

```
    Names           IDs         Address
0   [Mark, Jim, Ed] [2, 3, 5]   [road y, road v, road x]
1   [Jhon, Jiulia]  [1, 7]      [road b, road a]
2   [Phil]          [10]        [road z]
```

Comment: This isn't a general solution. OP wants to keep the integrity of `Names` and `Address` columns with respect to  the `sorted(IDs)` column

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response but the output is not what I was trying to get, The sort needs to happen on IDs but the index of the list changed after the sorting needs to be the same on the Names and Address columns, You can see the output needed is different from the one you generated

Comment: this command adapted to my dataframe triggers this error ( if not all(counts0 == self[c].apply(mylen)):) but it could be my fault since in my giant dataframe there is a column that is not a list, I'll remove that one and try again

Comment: I can't tell the cause from one line of error, without the code and full description of the error. It likely be a candidate for separate question, as the solution here addressed the stated question.

Comment: It works but I made a mistake, the element of the list are numbers as string not int, I adjusted the question, would it work with a similar command? or do I need to convert all the elements in the lists in the column into integers?

Comment: id does but reorders alphabetically in this way ['1', '11', '12', '2', '29', '3', etc...]

Comment: Thanks, I managed to fix it by making a function myself but yours is more elegant! I'll use yours!

Comment: @Diagnosta89, if solution worked for you and using it, would you consider, accepting the answer and upvoting it? StackOverflow synonym for a thank you is accepting and upvoting   https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers